# bootstrap 4 data-trigger='focus' not working on div

Tags: bootstrap-4, popover

the first div popover works fine although the p-3 class is not working.

the second popover on the button with data-trigger='focus' works as expected

the third popover, again on a div with data-trigger='focus' does not seem to work.

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 100px!important;
  border: solid 2px green;
}

div,button {
  margin-bottom: 20px!important;
  display:inline-block;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <h2>Popover Example</h2>
  <div class="p-3" data-toggle='popover' data-placement='top' data-content='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'>
    Toggle popover div
  </div><br>


  <button  data-trigger='focus' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='top' data-content='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'>
                Toggle popover div
  </button>
<br>
  <div  data-trigger='focus' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='top' data-content='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'>
    Toggle popover div
  </div><br>
  
<div  data-trigger='hover' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='top' data-content='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'>
    Toggle popover div
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 h3s on the page. Your styles are applied to both, as you can see with the green border. A margin inside the popover will affect the height.

Comment: thanks, I discovered that but found other issues.  see updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can't have focus on a div.  if we change the trigger to hover it works as expected.